# Microsoft Visual Studio git repository information error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git, github

I pushed my project to GitHub yesterday, and today when I tried to continue working on it, I encountered this issue while building the project.

Error reading git repository information: Invalid reference: '

I searched online but couldn't find a solution to this specific issue. I found similar problems, but I they are not applicable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I tried to pull remote repo through console when i tried
`git pull` console showed me an error which is

> myusername/myproject.git did not send all necessary objects

and also showed me where is the problem and i deleted this branch then i tried to pull again and it solved